# what the keyword "cnxn" means in zookeeper

Tags: apache-zookeeper

in zookeeper, there are many classNames which contains the keyword "cnxn", but there is no info when i search it's meaning by search engine.

could somebody tell me what's the meaning?

Answer (score 1):

This is just [an abbreviation of the word "connection"](https://www.lingo2word.com/lingodetail.php?WrdID=306577).

These classes are responsible for client/server connections, e.g. [ServerCnxn](https://zookeeper.apache.org/doc/current/apidocs/zookeeper-server/org/apache/zookeeper/server/ServerCnxn.html).